# method pointer and object reference

Tags: groovy

Where Groovy stores the reference to the variables used inside class method, which I transformed into closure.

In this example

```
class Accumulator {
    def count = 0

    def accumulate() {
        print (++count)
    }
}

def ac_inst= new Accumulator()
3.times {
    ac_inst.accumulate() //123
}
def accum = ac_inst.&accumulate
ac_inst = 5 // changed reference

8.times {
    accum() //4567891011
}
```

I created closure `accum` using method `accumulate` of `ac_inst` object - instance of `MyClass`.

The I changed `ac_inst` value to completely different object, but closure invokation continued to increment `count` value despite not having `ac_inst` object anymore.

Where it stores the required values for that closure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A closure has a `delegate` (which may be modified) and an `owner` (which strickly speaking can not)

So the instance it relates to is stored in here, and just changing the value it was originally from isn't going to change it.

Indeed this is true of pretty much every part of the language I can think of:

```
def list = [1,2,3]
def val = list[1]

list = [4,5,6]
println val // still 2
```

Comment: In the case of a MethodClosure, the instance is not stored as a delegate, but as his owner

Comment: @JérémieB True...  Updated first line

Answer (score 2):

When you are writting `def accum = ac_inst.&accumulate`, groovy create an instance of `MethodClosure` (and not a new class overriding Closure)

This object store the instance in his `owner` field and the method name in a `method` property. This is not a 'real closure', call() is only delegated to his owner. An `owner` can't be changed - it's a constant -, whereas a `delegate` can.

See [MethodClosure.java](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/d3bc07e5c2af7f5fbd344a961d549772de0680c7/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/MethodClosure.java)

Comment: This solved some questions of mine. Though note the `owner` can be "changed" using [`Closure.rehydrate`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/Closure.html#rehydrate(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object))